# YYYY-MM format in SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

My dataset that I am using to create my SQL database has datapoints that are formatted as YYYY-MM, but as far as I have found there isn't a format for SQL in order to store that specifically.
I am using Python and pyodbc to create a script that builds this database and updates it.

Is there any solution for this datatype within SQL that I am missing, or perhaps some way to solve this problem using the tools available in Pandas or something in Python?

Comment: Dates aren't stored with a format. If you want to store March 2022, store an actual date, e.g. `20220301`. If you want to format it as `YYYY-MM` on _read_, there are tons of ways to do that (preferably in your presentation layer).

Comment: As suggested by @AaronBertrand  in presentation layer you can format it as your want and in DB you can store it as string

Comment: Completely agree @AaronBertrand, just store the date in sql server as a datetime, and then format the data however you want in the application.

Comment: To drive home the point, sql-server stores DATE as a byte-reversed number of days since the year 0001-01-01, stored as three bytes. There is no format included in that three bytes, just a particular day using that calculation and storage methodology. The format is how it displays that three-byte number to us humans. So store your dates as dates and when you SELECT, tell it what format to show you `YYYY-MM`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand So, I sort of was guessing that was how it worked, but when I was reading in my data from the Dataframe that I loaded my CSV into, I get an error from SQL saying that the conversion failed converting date and/or time from character string, so I am not understanding what I need to do in order to alleviate that. I have the field in the database set as a date

Comment: Well the string literal YYYY-MM is not enough information for a date.  That only contains the month and year. For it to be a date it must also have the day. So maybe you could use the first day of the month? Then you would just want append "01" to the value that you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't fix the python source to output a date instead of part of a date, we can handle this a different way.

Let's say your real table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PythonInput
(
  SomeKey int CONSTRAINT PK_pi PRIMARY KEY,
  EventDate date
);
```

Create a staging table that mimics it, except that the date column is actually a string:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Staging_PythonInput
(
  SomeKey int CONSTRAINT PK_st_pi PRIMARY KEY,
  EventDate char(7)
);
```

Now you can have a trigger that just moves the data to your real table after massaging the date column:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.CorrectBadPythonInput
ON dbo.Staging_PythonInput
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
  INSERT dbo.PythonInput
  (
    SomeKey, 
    EventDate
  )
  SELECT 
    i.SomeKey, 
    TRY_CONVERT(date, i.EventDate + '-01', 120)
  FROM inserted AS i;
```

Then tell Python to insert into your staging table instead, e.g.:

```
INSERT dbo.Staging_PythonInput(SomeKey, EventDate)
  VALUES(1, '2022-07'), (2, '2022-03'), 
        (3, '2019-05'), (4, '0123-67');
```

Now a query against the source table:

```
SELECT SomeKey, EventDate FROM dbo.PythonInput;
```

Yields:

| SomeKey | EventDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-01 |
| 2 | 2022-03-01 |
| 3 | 2019-05-01 |
| 4 | *null* |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ab082c25df85c5da7f426ab05d717f04)

If you want to prevent the row with the invalid date from getting in, you can just add this to the trigger:

```
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, i.EventDate + '-01', 120) IS NOT NULL;
```

(And then you could run a different insert into a logging table if you want to track rows that were rejected.)

Comment: This solution is the one I have implemented with a few minor tweaks to match my code, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server supports XML data type, XQuery, XPath, and XSD.

XML has 49 data types. One of them is `xs:gYearMonth`.

It holds data in the following format: **yyyy-MM**. Exactly what we need.

First, we would need to create a UDF function. Otherwise, we will get the following error:

```
Xml data type methods are not supported in check constraints. Create a scalar user-defined function to wrap the method invocation. The error occurred at table "".
```

After that we will use that UDF in a regular check constraint.

To run a negative test, just uncomment a commented line in the `INSERT` statement.

**SQL**

```
USE tempdb;
GO

/*
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.CheckYearMonthXML;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckYearMonthXML(
     @yearMonth AS CHAR(7)
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @IsValid AS BIT
    
     IF TRY_CAST('<r><![CDATA[' + @yearMonth + ']]></r>' AS XML)
            .value('(/r/text())[1] cast as xs:gYearMonth?','CHAR(7)') IS NOT NULL
          SET @IsValid = 1
     ELSE
          SET @IsValid = 0
         
     RETURN @IsValid
END
GO

-- test
DECLARE @var CHAR(7) = '2022-12';
SELECT dbo.CheckYearMonthXML(@var);
*/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.tbl;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl (
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    yearMonth CHAR(7),
    CONSTRAINT CK_tbl_yearMonth CHECK (dbo.CheckYearMonthXML(yearMonth) = 1)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.tbl (yearMonth) VALUES
('2022-12'),
--('2022-22'),
('2022-08');

SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl;
```

Comment: I doubt that it was the OP's original intent. The OP wants to store data from the file in the db, and found that **yyyy-MM** is not directly supported by SQL Server by using built-in data types.

Comment: Let's wait for the OP's feedback.

Comment: I ended up implementing the other solution, as it was a bit simpler, and after some discussion with my team and overview of the dataset we determined the more simple solution was acceptable, and we can deal with the appended -01.
This solution was great though, I appreciate the response!